# Ember-Data 1.13.X : How to request included resources?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm converting my app over to the new version of `ember-data` (`1.13.5`).

I'd like to be able to request a set of resources (e.g. `this.store.findAll('post')`), maintain the background reloading behaviour that comes out of the box, but **also** request that a set of related resources be included from the server.

i.e. something like:

`this.store.findAll('post', { include: ["comments"] }`

This can obviously be done with a `query`, but I'm assuming that kills all of the background reloading stuff?

Comment: Ember data does not provide machinery for these kind of "meta" query parameters that are kind of instructions to the server. You most likely are going to end up writing your own version of `findAll` to handle them.

Comment: @torazaburo Humbug - I was hoping not to have to do that! Thanks for the info.  If you add a bit of info pointing me in the right direction on *how* to do this, I'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

**I think what you are trying to do is sideload your *comments* together with the *post*.**

I don't know how your server code for that is written, for instance in my case where I use *laravel* for the serverside,

- I would check for the include parameter in the controller code for retrieving the post. If *include comments* directive has been specified, then I would take advantage of a builtin mechanism that *laravel* provides where you specify whether you want a model *with* its related models, i.e `return post->with('comments');`
  And then with the help of a custom json serializer, you can extract the *comments* and add to the json for the *post* .

But outside of laravel, an algorithm like this would do in the serverside code for retrieving posts

1. Retrieve all the posts.
2. Check for the include parameter. If it's specified, retrieve the comments that belong to each post.
3. Then write code that creates a json result merging the json result for *post* with its *comments* together.